# Assigning a Azure Key Valult name as a variable in YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have this piece of code :

```
- name: SQLPasswordEnvironment 
  ${{ if eq(parameters.libraryGroup, 'RAPTDevEnv') }}:
    value: 'SQLServerAdminPassword-RAPT-DEV'
  ${{ if eq(parameters.libraryGroup, 'RAPTUatEnv') }}:
    value: 'SQLServerAdminPassword-RAPT-UAT'
  ${{ if eq(parameters.libraryGroup, 'RAPTPreProdEnv') }}:
    value: 'SQLServerAdminPassword-RAPT-PreProd'
  ${{ if eq(parameters.libraryGroup, 'RAPTProdEnv') }}:
    value: 'SQLServerAdminPassword-RAPT-Prod'
```

so if a user chooses RAPTDevEnv then the value is the name of the key in azure keyvault.

and when i use the azure key valult task (to filter to get that key only)

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Get secrets terraform-init'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ATP DevOps Service Connection'
    KeyVaultName: $(KeyVault)
    SecretsFilter: $SQLPasswordEnvironment
    RunAsPreJob: false
```

it tries to fine the key called $SQLPasswordEnvironment and not the value of that variable.

how can this be done in yaml, azure devops with key vault ?

Comment: You may have your reasons.... but normally you have one keyvault per environment, with identical secret names in each keyvault instance

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - completely agree but its possible.

Comment: Hi Jason, if you find the solution, please don't forget to [mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Nd8.png) the solution as the answer of this question. This will help others who encounter the similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Get secrets terraform-init'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ATP DevOps Service Connection'
    KeyVaultName: $(KeyVault)
    SecretsFilter: '$(SQLPasswordEnvironment)' 
    RunAsPreJob: false
```

Simple change, just add the '' before and at the end of the variable

Comment: The lack of single quotes isn't the problem. The variable expansion syntax was incorrect. `$SQLPasswordEnvironment` vs `$(SQLPasswordEnvironment)`.